# Looped property c#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

```
    static TestInitialization()
    {
      client = new HttpClient();
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri( URL_BASE_ADRESS );
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "auth-key", Auth_Token );
    }

    private const String path = @"f:\specialproject\authdata.txt";
    internal static readonly String Login = File.ReadLines( path ).First(); //login in this file must be the first line
    internal static readonly String Password = File.ReadLines( path ).Last();//password - as second line
    internal static String Auth_Token
    {
      get
      {
        if( Auth_Token != null )
          return Auth_Token;
        else
          return LoginAndGetToken();
      }
      set
      {
        Auth_Token = LoginAndGetToken();
      }
    }

    internal static String LoginAndGetToken()
    {
      HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, $"{URL_BASE_ADRESS}/console/home/login" );
      request.Content = new StringContent( "{\"login\":\"" + TestInitialization.Login + "\",\"password\":\"" + TestInitialization.Password + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" );

      Auth_Token = client.SendAsync( request ).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Headers.GetValues( "auth-key" ).ToArray()[ 0 ];
      return Auth_Token;
    }
```

This is part of my code. When the static constructor is executed and I try to get the `Auth-Key` property - in the getter it gets looped while checking for null.

How can I implement this logic? (Without adding an additional private field)
If the value is null, the `set` block is executed. Or the `LoginAndGetToken()` method with a return value.

Comment: The property is reading itself, causing a stack overflow. You need an additional private field.

Comment: I understand this, but is it possible to do it without the extra field? I indicated this in the question.

Comment: The issue here is that you're not clear what you *want*. You say "it gets looped". Is that an observation about what your code currently does and you don't want it to do, or do you actually want the static constructor to wait for the auto token to be set? You need to tell us what your goal is, only then can we tell you how to fix it. (the static constructor should not wait though, but let's start with what your goal is)

Comment: But a property either need to be calculated from something, or it needs storage. You can't implement a property, with code, and get the storage automatically. If you need the storage, you need to add a private field or another property or whatnot to act as the storage for the property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, thanks to everyone, for good advice, I decided to do it all the same through an additional field. Here's the answer:

```
    private static String _auth_token;
    internal static String Auth_Token
    {
      get
      {
        if( _auth_token != null )
          return _auth_token;
        else
          return _auth_token = LoginAndGetToken();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the

```cs
    internal static String Auth_Token
    {
      get
      {
        if( Auth_Token != null )
          return Auth_Token;
        else
          return LoginAndGetToken();
      }
      set
      {
        Auth_Token = LoginAndGetToken();
      }
    }
```

has two stack overflow cases.
First one is in the `get` (`return Auth_Token`) and another one in the `set` (`LoginAndGetToken` method sets the `Auth_Token` value)

I'd like to suggest to use `Lazy<T>` with factory like

```cs
internal static Lazy<String> Auth_Token = new Lazy<String>(LoginAndGetToken);

internal static String LoginAndGetToken()
{
  HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, $"{URL_BASE_ADRESS}/console/home/login" );
  request.Content = new StringContent( "{\"login\":\"" + TestInitialization.Login + "\",\"password\":\"" + TestInitialization.Password + "\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json" );

  return client.SendAsync( request ).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Headers.GetValues( "auth-key" ).ToArray()[ 0 ];
}
```

this may be used as below `Auth_Token.Value` to call :

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "auth-key", Auth_Token.Value );
```

PS *no additional field* condition looks strange (and `Auth_Token` is not a field it is the property)

PPS is it a homework? Is there method quantity limitation? You can have one `Auth_Token` property just to store a string value and the method `GetAuth_Token()` to return `Auth_Token` or call `LoginAndGetToken` if there is no `Auth_Token` value

```cs
string GetAuth_Token()
{
  return Auth_Token = Auth_Token ?? LoginAndGetToken();
}
```

Comment: I never said that Autn_Key is a field: /
Does my code look so bad?)) No, this is not homework, this is really a working program, but I have changed some parts of the program to make it easier to understand my question.
I was just wondering if there is a way to do this without the extra field, that's all.
I already realized that a method with a private field is the most convenient way out.

Comment: @Artnoxips probably you have changed a lot since two stack overflow cases are too much for working program

Answer (score 1):

When using the shortcut property implementation, e.g.:

```
public string MyProp { get; set; }
```

the underlying field is implicitly created.

But when any implementation for accessors is provided, this implicit field is not created. If the property needs to keep any state you have to define the needed fields yourself, e.g.:

```
public string MyProp
{
    get
    {
       if (myProp == null)
           myProp = SomeCodeToComputeMyProp();
       return myProp;
    }
    set
    {
        myProp = value;
    }
}
private string myProp = null;
```

Additional notes:

- The setter is supposed to use the (implicit) `value` parameter and set the property based on it. While it is perfectly valid for it to do some additional checking and calculations it should not be doing something completely different. Ignoring `value` and doing something completely different as you do indicated that something is very wrong with your design. Maybe there should be no setter at all? Or only a private one for use inside your class?
- It is confusing and error prone from your class client perspective when property accessors perform expensive or blocking tasks. HTTP requests should be perfomed in normal methods not inside properties.

And [oleksa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65478283/69585) is right: In this case you probably want the `Lazy<T>` pattern anyways.

Comment: This code has been written hastily to describe what I want to achieve.
In reality, this piece looks different.